# UWP SerialDevice works only if I read it's properties

Tags: c#, serial-port, uwp, win-universal-app

So, I have some code for setting up my serial port in UWP (which is used with an USB-to-Serial adapter):

```
public async Task Init() 
{
        string qFilter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM5"); 
        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(qFilter);
        deviceId = devices.First().Id;
        var serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

        serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        serialPort.BaudRate = 4800;
        serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
}
```

now, somewhere later in the code, I read a stream from the SerialDevice:

```
public async Task<string> ReadValueFromSerial()
{
        var dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;
        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        //set timeout here.
        cts.CancelAfter(10000);
        var bytesRead = await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cts.Token);
        (...)
}
```

no above code hangs on the last line, altough I know, that the serial device is sending bytes to the serial port.

Funny thing is, that it works, when I put a breakpoint on the set-up part (the first snippet). But without a breakpoint and stepping through it, it just hangs, or times out.

By trials and errors I found out, that reading the serial device properties which I set in the set-up code, makes it magically work.

So after the code in the first snippet, I have added:

```
public async Task Init() 
{
         (...)
         var s1 = " " + serialPort.BaudRate;
         var s2 = " " + serialPort.DataBits;
         var s3 = " " + serialPort.Parity.ToString();
}
```

And now the `var bytesRead = await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cts.Token);` doesn't hang anymore and the bytes are loaded. It works, which is great, but why?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the same problem as you.  Your workaround works for me as well, so thanks for that.  I've been fighting this issue for days.  Did you ever find out what causes this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't found the reason, but it works :)

Comment: Incredible ! 6 years later, I face the same problem, and your workaround still works. Thanks. I'd love to have an explanation and a clean way to solve the issue.